# Magento Shipment Email Confirmation Being Sent Twice

Tags: magento-1.7, email

Our shipment confirmation email is being sent twice.

They email templates look the same except one email includes tracking while the other does not. This only happens with shipment confirmations, and not with new order notification emails.

Ship confirm email being sent twice:
[image]

Magento Sales Emails Settings:
[image]

How do I prevent 2 shipment email confirmations from being sent? I've been trying for several days but I'm having a hard time.

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The data that is used to determine whether the customer has been notified is stored in `sales_flat_shipment_comment`, in the `is_customer_notified` field. The code that controls sending the email is in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment->sendEmail()`. I suggest overriding that class and method, and then querying the shipment comment collection to see if the customer has been notified.